# How to switch between Fuduntu to Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, usb, system-installation, usb-creator

I am using Fuduntu at the moment but i need to Switch to Ubuntu. The main thing is that i can use FreeCad and many other Soft-wares that are available in Ubuntu and not in Fuduntu .How can switch between Fuduntu to Ubuntu by using a bootable USB flash memory? because in my laptop i don't have CD player to boot from. I tried finding a way to boot my USB flash memory but i couldn't find anything helpful. If you can help on this issue it will be very appreciated

Regards,
Duaij

Answer (score 2):

Please check out this official How To by Ubuntu to create a bootable USB drive *on Windows*:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

I don't know if you also have this option in Fuduntu but you could try to do it this way:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

You can even do it on a Mac:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

I hope this answers your question.